# How to have a cropped video on top of another video in imovie?

Tags: imovie

In youtube I see our lot of cropped videos overlaid over screen captures movie. Is this possible in imovie?

osX
imovie 10.1.2

Comment: Please add info such as versions of OS, iMovie. Do you possibly have QT pro?

Comment: no quick time pro for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to have a cropped video on top of another video in imovie?

This is known as Picture in Picture.

**The following instructions are for versions of iMovie 10.1+**

1. Open a project and add a movie to timeline
2. Select and drag a second clip above the main clip based on where in the video timeline you would like for it to show.
3. Select Picture in Picture from the Overlay drop down menu.
4. Drag the movie clip to where you want it placed on video preview screen and resize if needed.

That's it. Enjoy!

Note: You can use the same method for text and photos as well.

[image]

Comment: I have no options for advanced tools in prefs

Comment: I will shortly update the answer based on new info.

Comment: @SuperUberDuper please see updated answer.

Comment: cool cheers mate!